# JBAS017354: Could not find the port number listening for protocol javax.ws.rs.core.Application

Tags: java, web-services, rest, wildfly

I am trying to deploy a war, which JAX-RS annotations in wildfly server.
Below is the web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org /xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My Service class:

```
@Path("/gms")
public class GmsService {

    @Path("/saveMS")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void saveMeasurements(MainBean mb){
        System.out.println(mb.getStationID());
        System.out.println(mb.getMeasurements().get(0));
    }
}
```

The problem is that it cannot be deployed due to the error below:
JBAS017354: Could not find the port number listening for protocol javax.ws.rs.core.Application

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and here is how I fixed it :

If you check out this page : http://fossies.org/linux/www/wildfly-8.0.0.Final-src.tar.gz/wildfly-8.0.0.Final-src/undertow/src/main/java/org/wildfly/extension/undertow/UndertowMessages.java

you can see that the exception code 17354 is "servletClassNotDefined", so you just need to define one.

In your web.xml, define the servlet-class this way :

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

It worked like a charm for me.

I hope it helps!

Val

Comment: according to the JSR this is not required. so technically it's a Wildfly bug

Answer (score 0):

Actually, even if the previous solution made the exception disappear, the underlying issue was that my wildfly was running on a jdk7 and I was compiling my .war with a jdk1.8.

If the previous answer doesn't work, remove the class definition in your web.xml and modify the jre running your wildfly.